# Java string array with setter getter

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, setter

I wanted to create a simple program for user to insert 3 strings to a private string array in a class and then print it back by creating a new object using object reference but I think I am facing problem in the setter/getter.(Pretty new to class and setter/getter) Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stringtest {
public static void main(String[] args)
{   Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);


   Stringer Strung=new Stringer();

    System.out.println("Strings:"+Strung.print());


}
}
class Stringer
{   Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    private String[] aa=new String[3];
    aa[0]="zero";
    aa[1]="one";
    aa[2]="two";

    Stringer()
    {}

{  System.out.println("Please enter 3 strings:");

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        aa[i]=input.next();
    }
}

public  void setaa(String[] a)
{
    aa=a;
}

public String[] getaa()
{
    return aa;
}

public void print(String[] a)
{
    for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s",a[b]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What is your observed outout. Also, you use an [initializer block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). I would suggest moving the logic from the initializer block to the constructor. Furhtermore, in the initializer and the `print()`-method, the `for` loops from `0` to `3` (both inclusive), but the array only has a length of `3` (indices `0` to `2`), so this will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. --- While you have written a getter and a setter for `aa` (which I suggest to be renamed for clarity), but you do not use them.

Comment: and a hint: if you want to loop over all elements of an array, normally `for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++)` is used - so if the size of he array is changed, the code still works

Comment: Ah,sorry I think I forgot to initialize the string array to a few strings.I wanted to have the setter and getter so user input can replace the initialized private string array by creating a new object class

Answer (score 1):

1. Due to populating the array while creating a class instance, you don't require any setters. The only getter requires.
2. Divide the logic from the runner.
3. Always use `array.length()` while looping or use a simple `for` loop otherwise you'll be getting an `indexOfBoudException` error.
4. Didn't get why you are using `printf()` while printing results.

   My solution:

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class App {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           App.run();
       }

       private static void run() {
           Stringer stringer = new Stringer();
           stringer.print(stringer.getStrings());
       }
   }

   class Stringer {

       private String[] strings = new String[3];

       Stringer() {
           System.out.println("Please enter 3 strings:");
           for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
               Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
               strings[i] = scanner.next();
           }
       }

       String[] getStrings() {
           return strings;
       }

       void print(String[] strings) {
           System.out.println("Strings are:");
           for (String string : strings) {
               System.out.println(string);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I forgot to initialize the array but I wanted to use setter/getter for when creating a new object class I can reference to the class to access and modify the private string array

Comment: According to your code and the purpose you’ve declared setter is unnecessary.There’s the code convention: don’t have unused classes / methods / variables ‘just in case’.